# Referencing values in another table using g:each

Tags: grails

Using Grails, I am looping through an array in a view using a `<g:each />` tag, however I want to use the values in the array as a reference to foreign key in another table in the database, in the same loop.

Is it possible to create a string of variable references to other tables? for example:

```
${productId.Users.UserId}
```

Comment: Can you expand a little bit?  From your statement of the problem productId sounds like it is just that - a number, not an instance variable.  If so I'm not sure how to interpret ${productId.Users.UserId}.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do something like ...

```
//Assuming this is the list to run through your <g:each>
def list = ['userId1', 'userId2', 'userId3']
```

And assuming the values of the above list are some attribute of some table or data model you have like...

```
def model = [
  userId1: 'John Doe',
  userId2: 'Jane Doe',
  userId3: 'Jack Doe'
]
```

If the above is the scenario you're thinking of, then you should be able to do something like this...

```
<g:each in="${list}" var="element">
   ${model[element]}
</g:each>

//output
John Doe
Jane Doe
Jack Doe
```